# krita shows critical error on Linux Mint

Tags: software-installation, kde

I installed `krita' software into Linux Mint but it shows critical error. Which dependencies should I install on my Linux Mint? I reinstalled krita but the problem still remains?

[image: krita]

I followed this procedure:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install krita
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: You are running a Windows version of Krita on Mint.]

You are running a Windows version of Krita on Mint. You need to install the native version of Krita. Use Synaptic or apt-get to install it.

Krita runs fine on Mint if you use the native version.

[image: Krita runs just fine on Mint]

Comment: I follow this procedure which given by official site:sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install krita

Comment: can give details for native version. Because `krita` working on Ubuntu but not work on Mint..

Comment: i've got the same problem, and i installed krita through the software manager.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install krita
sudo apt-get install kritasketch 
sudo apt-get install kdelibs-bin
kbuildsycoca4
```

(the kritasketch package provides you the sketch brush in 2.8.0)

Comment: kbuildsycoca4 running...
kbuildsycoca4(7802): "applications.menu"  not found in  ("/home/doeke/.config/menus/", "/etc/xdg/menus/")

Comment: I get the above error on kbuildsycoca4

Answer (score 1):

@taringa's answer is the correct answer. Specifically, you are missing the KDE configuration database (because you aren't using the KDE desktop). You need to run [`kbuildsyscoca4`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/kbuildsycoca4.8.html) which is located in the `kdelibs-bin` package. Despite the `.exe` extension, this has nothing to do with "running a Windows version" on Mint.

See [*here*](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2261878) for more information.

So at provided you've done this or installed through software manager:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install krita
```

You then, at minimum, must:

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs-bin
kbuildsycoca4
```

The `kritasketch` package is optional to get the sketch brush.

I would have just upvoted and commented on @taringa's answer but I have neither of those privileges yet :)

Comment: > kbuildsycoca4 running...
kbuildsycoca4(7802): "applications.menu"  not found in  ("/home/doeke/.config/menus/", "/etc/xdg/menus/")

Comment: I get the above error on kbuildsycoca4

Answer (score 0):

run in terminal

```
  kbuildsycoca4 --noincremental
```

then start krita